# Hide BLE devices from Genric BLE scanner apps

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Is there any way to hide BLE devices from Generic BLE scanning apps like BleExplr, LightBlue etc?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure your peripheral to use service solicitation. In this mode the central offers services and the peripheral scans for them -refer to page 21 of this document - https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=245130.

Note that even with service solicitation a Bluetooth analyser will be able to receive the service advertisement from the central but apps like LightBlue won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide BLE devices, The BLExplr and LightBlue are application using as center mode, these apps can find devices as BLE peripheral mode. As the BLE concept, the peripheral devices broadcast and allow to any center mode devices range to see them. Please see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) to get more information